# How to use mysql full-text search in node by using escape() method?

Tags: mysql, node.js

In node js I used to run a LIKE statement query to get data from MYSQL database, however, due to poor performances I have updated my query to use full-text search ("where match AGAINST" statement).  I tried to run the query with a "?" placeholder or by using escape() method (to avoid sql injection) but with no success. The query only ran successfully without having the "?" placeholder or escape() method.

I have looked up other answers provided but couldn't find a solution to this.

code **works** - *sql-injection vulnerable*

```
function (req,res,next) {
/// req.query.Name is coming from user input of a form
    const queryString = "Select idx, descr, price, product_img,\
 stock, available from prod.product_list_details where match descr \
    against" + "(" + "'" + req.query.Name + "'" + ")"
    connection.query(queryString, (err, rows, fields) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Failed to query for description: " + err)
        res.sendStatus(500)
        return
      }
      console.log("I think we fetched products successfully")
```

code **doesn't work** - *added ? placeholder to avoid sql injection*

```
function (req,res,next) {
///productDescription is from user input of a form
    var productDescription = "(" + "'" + req.query.Name+ "'" + ")" 
    const queryString = "Select idx, descr, price, product_img, stock,\
 available from prod.product_list_details where match descr against ?" 
    connection.query(queryString, productDescription, 
      (err, rows, fields) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Failed to query for description: " + err)
        res.sendStatus(500)
        return
      }
      console.log("I think we fetched products successfully")
```

Error message that I'm getting with second query:

Failed to query for description: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''(\'Clorox\')'' at line 1

Is there any way to use mysql full-text search in node js and also have a way to avoid sql injection?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

**EDIT**
Thanks for the answer, this is what worked for me.

```
function (req,res,next) {
    var userInput = req.query.Name ///values to search
    var modifiedUserInput = userInput.replace(/ /g,"+")
    var productDescription = "'+" + modifiedUserInput+ "'" 
    const queryString = "Select idx, descr, price, product_img, stock, available from \
    prod.product_list_details where match descr against (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)" 
    connection.query(queryString, productDescription, 
      (err, rows, fields) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Failed to query for description: " + err)
        res.sendStatus(500)
        return
      }
      console.log("I think we fetched products successfully")
```

Comment: `+ "'" + req.query.Name + "'" ` - this is sql-injection vulnerability! see: https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: ` where match descr against ?` doesn't seem right. Do you mean `WHERE descr MATCH ?`?

Comment: @tadman here is the link to mysql syntax, thanks! - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Comment: @alfasin - you meant even with "?" placeholder, this is sql-injection vulnerability, as shown in the second query?

Comment: @SnowKari Ah, I see what you're trying to do now. This would be a lot easier to read with the redundancy removed and with placeholders used instead of concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using placeholders it's important to note that these are for *data only* and that syntax elements cannot be included, it will result in a parsing error.

In your case it means the query should be of the form:

```
WHERE MATCH (descr) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Where `?` represents the data to be included, and only the data. When you put in the brackets it effectively expands to this:

```
WHERE MATCH (descr) AGAINST '(...)'
```

That breaks the syntax because the brackets are now inside the data instead of surrounding the data.

For things like `LIKE` where the `%` placeholders are part of the data, you put them in like this:

```
WHERE x LIKE ?
```

In other cases you can do:

```
WHERE x LIKE CONCAT('%', ?)
```

If you'd prefer to do the assembly database-side.

In any case, using prepared statements with placeholder values is extremely important so getting a handle on this is a big deal and it's great that you're working in that direction.

Hope that helps get you where you want to go.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Sorry for the confusion about concatenation (will edit my question). Yes, I'm trying to run the query based off user input of the form (req.query.Name).  With the concatenation, it would give me ('Name'), so the query runs successfully without using "?" placeholder, it's the first query that i attached. However, when I tried to use with "?" placeholder, it returned an error.  I'm trying to stay away from LIKE statement as the query takes a long time to run. Is there any other suggestions?  Thanks so much!

Comment: I think you're missing the point here. Placeholders like `?` are for *data only*. Any syntax elements need to be put into the prepared statement. So `AGAINST ?` will not work, imagine that expands to `AGAINST '(...)'` which is not valid. `AGAINST (?)` *will*.

Comment: It worked, thanks so much! really appreciate your explanation!